# Output Post ID for all nav_items

Tags: menus, navigation, id

I seek a solution for my navigation in a new WordPress template that I'm developing.

How can I output the unique post ID for every nav item?

I want to create a one-pager (microsite) for a client.

Before I tried something with walker-nav and other things that didn't work.

Comment: if you want it through javascript for client side, you can extract id's from html mark up. Wordpress adds id for each item.

Comment: mmh, thanks for your reply, i thinked also i can do something with js... but i planned the template in php. i include all post_id's in the microsite content from the navigation in a foreach to check the main nav. so i need the id in a php var.. i can also convert the javascript var in php, but this is not really that quality i wan't to create. is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html mark up for navigation will look like this

```
<ul id="menu-res" class="main-menu"><li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-72"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-238"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-73"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-75"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-346"><a href="http://www.yourstorepick.com/pro-site/">Pro Site</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-347"><a href="http://www.yourstorepick.com/wp-signup.php?pro-site=1">Sign up</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-74"><a href="#our-team">Our Team</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-239"><a href="#our-work">Our Work</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-236" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-236"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-237" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-237"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

From above code you can see that each li has unique ID, in this `menu-item-XXX` is a format of ID. `menu-item-` will be same and `XXX` will vary. You can extract this ID.

Comment: okay, then i think there is no other solutions possible. i will try this now, and give you feedback. thanks for first

Comment: I haven't tried but this can be done with custom walker class also. But that would be lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the corresponding post ID's from a given menu id, try:

```
$menu_id = 'mymenu'; 
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
$ids = ( $items ) ? wp_list_pluck( $items , 'object_id' ) : array();
```

where you have to modify the `$menu_id` to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, I have tried the solution with javascript. It works without problems.

For debug test:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        alert($('.menu-item').attr('id'));
    });
</script>
```

It gives me the id from every element in the nav out as alert. I extract now the number at the end and have then the menu-item-id.

thanks for all answers, cheers :)

Comment: this should be in loop